# Using color and background color together

Tags: fonts, formatting, color

I'm trying to use `color` and `background` color together. But, for example, the following is not working - showing only a black box. What I may be missing here and how can it be fixed.?

**Remark**: I'm using `MikTeX` (with default installation) on my `Windows-10`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\title{\LaTeX}

\begin{document}
\[\colorbox{black}{\color{white}\LaTeX}\]

\end{document}
```

**Desired output**: Something like the following:

[image]

Comment: After loading `xcolor` package, it works on `texlive`. Does it make any difference by loading it in `MikTeX`?

Comment: The same is at MikTeX.

Comment: @AlanXiang Your suggestion worked on `MikTeX`, as well. It also worked with `color` package.

Comment: your example does not produce a black box, it will give an undefined command error for `\colorbox` so your question is very misleading.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle When I use `color` package, following works on my `MikTeX` installation on Windows-10. Am I not be doing something right here?: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}
  \[\colorbox{black}{\color{white}\LaTeX}\]
\end{document}`

Comment: That is not what you posted in the question. The error in the posted code is the missing color package and you state that it "showing only a black box" but that is not what happens with the code posted. What happens is that you get an error telling you the color commands are not defined.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Agreed. My mistake. Thank your for pointing it out, David.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reproduce showed image, try the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor} % <---
%\title{\LaTeX}

\begin{document}
\[
\colorbox{black}{\color{white}\textit{\LaTeX}} % <---
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your suggestion worked on `MikTeX` (thank you). I thought `color` package was a part of `amsmath` package. Obviously, I was wrong. It worked after I loaded `color` package. And, the same was true when I tried your suggestion of loading `xcolor` package. I suppose `xcolor` is an extension of `color` package.

Comment: @nam, you are right. `xcolor` is is an advanced color upgrade/supersede of the `color` package. With option `table`: `[table]{xcolor]` also  contain   advanced functionality of the  `colortbl` package.